# My GE front load washer not starting, all tests are good. No error code

Tags: washing-machine

My GE washer model GCVH6800JOMS is not starting. It's door lock and unlock and sits there when you press start. I checked, there is no error code. Almost all tests done, good.
Don't know what to do now.

Comment: This may sound silly but try unplugging it , wait a minute , press the on button. Then plug back in and see if it starts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how our site operates.

Comment: Thanks Ed, tried it but still same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the GE owners manual it lists the symptoms you describe. It says the door will lock and unlock and will take 30 seconds to do a system check. If it still doesn't start open and close the door firmly; then press start.

**Edit**
If this doesn't solve the problem you probably need a repairman. If it's within warranty - terrific. If not call a GE recommended professional. It may be possible that someone on this site can help you but we would need a lot of more detailed information including pictures. Even then if someone here could diagnose the issue you'd probably still have to call someone to fix it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it, no luck!